# Generate HTML Page with Specific Tags from Another Page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm exploring BeautifulSoup and aiming to retain only specific tags in an HTML file to create a new one.

I can successfully achieve this with the following program. However, I believe there might be a more suitable and natural approach without the need to manually append the strings.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

with open('P:/Test.html', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup= BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')

NewHTML = "<html><body>"
NewHTML+="\n"+str(soup.find('title'))
NewHTML+="\n"+str(soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'm-b-0'}))
NewHTML+="\n"+str(soup.find('div', attrs={'id' :'right-col'}))
NewHTML+= "</body></html>"

with open("output1.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(NewHTML)
```

Comment: how about standard `f-string`? `f"<html><body>{va1}\n{val2}\n{val3}"</body></html>"`. How about standard `.format()`? `"<html><body>{}\n{}\n{}"</body></html>".foramt(va1, val2, val3)`. For something more complex you could use `Jinja2` (which uses `Flask` to generate `HTML`

Comment: or maybe you should use `BeautifulSoup` to create HTML - see doc for [append](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append) and [extend](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extend)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a list of desired tags, iterate through them, and use Beautiful Soup's [append](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append) method to selectively include corresponding elements in the new HTML structure.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('Test.html', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')

new_html = BeautifulSoup("<html><body></body></html>", 'html.parser')

tags_to_keep = ['title', {'p': {'class': 'm-b-0'}}, {'div': {'id': 'right-col'}}]

# Iterate through the tags to keep and append them to the new HTML
for tag in tags_to_keep:
    # If the tag is a string, find it in the original HTML
    # and append it to the new HTML
    if isinstance(tag, str):
        new_html.body.append(soup.find(tag))
    # If the tag is a dictionary, extract tag name and attributes,
    # then find them in the original HTML and append them to the new HTML
    elif isinstance(tag, dict):
        tag_name = list(tag.keys())[0]
        tag_attrs = tag[tag_name]
        new_html.body.append(soup.find(tag_name, attrs=tag_attrs))

with open("output1.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(new_html))
```

Assuming you have an HTML document like the one below (which would have been helpful to include for reproducibility's sake):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="m-b-0">Paragraph with class 'm-b-0'.</p>
    <div id="right-col">
        <p>Paragraph inside the 'right-col' div.</p>
    </div>
    <p>Paragraph outside the targeted tags.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the resulting `output1.html` will contain the following content:

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <title>Test Page</title>
      <p class="m-b-0">Paragraph with class 'm-b-0'.</p>
      <div id="right-col">
         <p>Paragraph inside the 'right-col' div.</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works !
The solution given below by furas works also. 
the two guys are very helpful !

Answer (score 3):

For simple html I would use standard `f-string` or standard `.format()`

```
val1 = soup.find('title')
val2 = soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'm-b-0'})
val3 = soup.find('div', attrs={'id' :'right-col'})

# f-string
new_html = f"<html><body>\n{val1}\n{val2}\n{val3}\n</body></html>"

# .format
new_html = "<html><body>\n{}\n{}\n{}\n</body></html>".format(val1, val2, val3)
```

Python has also old method with `%`

```
new_html = "<html><body>\n%s\n%s\n%s\n</body></html>" % (val1, val2, val3)
```

---

There is also [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) but I never used it - because `f-string` can do the same.

```
from string import Template

template = Template('<html><body>\n$item1\n$item2\n$item3\n</body></html>')

new_html = template.substitute(item1=val1, item2=val2, item3=val3)
```

---

For something more complex I would use [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) which is used by `Flask()`.

```
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader

template = '<html><body>\n{{item1}}\n{{item2}}\n{{item3}}\n</body></html>'

rtemplate = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(template)

new_html = rtemplate.render(item1=val1, item2=val2, item3=val3)

print(new_html)
```

It allows to use `{% for %}`, `{% if %}`, etc directly in template - so I can send all values as `list` or `tuple` and use `for`-loop directly in template

```
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader

template = '<html><body>\n{% for val in items %}{{val}}\n{% endfor %}</body></html>'

rtemplate = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(template)

new_html = rtemplate.render(items=(val1,val2,val3))

print(new_html)
```

---

Of course you can also try to use `BeautifulSoup` to create HTML - see doc for [append](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append) and [extend](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append) - but I think that other methods are simpler. `BeautifulSoup` can be useful if you have already some (long) `HTML` and you want to replace or add some items.

---

Full code with all examples (except `BeautifulSoup`):

Instead of values from `soup.find()` I use literally `soup.find()`

```
val1 = "soup.find('title')"
val2 = "soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'm-b-0'})"
val3 = "soup.find('div', attrs={'id' :'right-col'})"

print('\n--- f-string ---\n')
new_html = f"<html><body>\n{val1}\n{val2}\n{val3}\n</body></html>"
print(new_html)

print('\n--- .format() ---\n')
new_html = "<html><body>\n{}\n{}\n{}\n</body></html>".format(val1, val2, val3)
print(new_html)

print('\n--- % ---\n')
new_html = "<html><body>\n%s\n%s\n%s\n</body></html>" % (val1, val2, val3)
print(new_html)

# ------------------

from string import Template

template = Template('<html><body>\n$item1\n$item2\n$item3\n</body></html>')

print('\n--- string.Template ---\n')
new_html = template.substitute(item1=val1, item2=val2, item3=val3)
print(new_html)

# ------------------

from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader

print('\n--- jinja ---\n')

template = '<html><body>\n{{item1}}\n{{item2}}\n{{item3}}\n</body></html>'
rtemplate = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(template)

new_html = rtemplate.render(item1=val1, item2=val2, item3=val3)
print(new_html)

print('\n--- jinja - {% for %} ---\n')

template = '<html><body>\n{% for val in items %}{{val}}\n{% endfor %}</body></html>'
rtemplate = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(template)

new_html = rtemplate.render(items=(val1,val2,val3))
print(new_html)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. I received an other solution which works too and I can approve only one ! Thank you for all your examples, ii is vey useful